# Blank screen after comment on mobile app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Something *funky* has been happening since the Stack Exchange app was updated on my iPhone: every time I write a comment, I get a success message, but the question goes blank and can’t interact with it.

Screenshots of the problem:

[image: Writing comment]

[image: Success writing comment]

[image: Blank question after comment]

The solution/workaround to the problem is simple: exit the question (the top bar is still there) and get back in, and everything will load fine (including the comment I wrote).

Is that something happening to more people, or is it only my iPhone? (6S for more detail.)

Comment: Adding a comment for screenshot

Comment: @Laurel yes, same issue (I should have searched for white instead of blank). Thanks for the link. Closing this one as duplicate.